# Angular2 Twig template loading

Tags: angular, templates, twig

I'm using Symfony and Angular2.

Is there a way to load the symonfy twig templates in angular2?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Group',
    templateUrl: './path/to/twig/group.component.html.twig'
})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://github.com/manekinekko/angular2-twig. The have a WIP that may help you.

By using this library you can (As stated in README file):

```
import {Twig} from 'angular2-twig';
@Twig({
    templateUrl: 'templates/field--comment.html.twig',
    // -or- template: '',
    context: {
        title: 'Angular2 ❤ Twig',
        content_1: 'content 1',
        content_2: 'content 2'
    },
    selector: '#block-content',
 })
 export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Answer is edited. Regarding my question i am researching now, after starving all resources at my hand i will ask.

Comment: @davidmpaz Yes :)